# GWT Unit Testing: Ignoring HtmlUnit JavaScript Exceptions

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, htmlunit

I'm trying to setup some unit testing for a GWT based project.

This project uses some JavaScript files that cause HtmlUnit to throw a exception and for the JUnit client to not even start properly, as they are based around the canvas component that HtmlUnit doesn't implement.

An abridged version of the logs would be the following:

```
Validating newly compiled units
   Ignored 27 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
Starting http://127.0.1.1:1234/com.name.project.JUnit/junit-standards.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.1.1:4321 on browser FF3
... (Some more GETs)
200 - GET /com.name.project.JUnit/junit-standards.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.1.1:4321 (127.0.0.1) 333 bytes
200 - GET/com.name.project.JUnit/com.name.project.JUnit.JUnit.nocache.js (1
27.0.0.1) 444 bytes
logging for HtmlUnit thread
   [WARN] Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://127.0.1.1:1234/com.name.project.JUnit/com.name.project.JUnit.nocache.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.

... A few more GETs

   [WARN] Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://127.0.1.1:1234/com.name.project.JUnit/culprit.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.

Exception in thread "htmlUnit client thread" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.WrappedException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking
 jsxFunction_write

... And an extremely long stacktrace detailing how HtmlUnit threw an exception because of a call to getImageData on a canvas
```

The scripts are not needed at all for the tests to run, so ideally they shouldn't even be loaded. Were this standalone HtmlUnit I know there's different ways around it such as:

- Creating a proxy connection that ignores certain files
- Disabling script exceptions setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false)

The problem is that I'm not quite sure how to achieve any of these while running HtmlUnit under the GWT testing framework, from what I've seen you cannot really get to configure the HtmlUnit WebClient that it creates.

Also I'm well aware that this: `@DoNotRunWith(com.google.gwt.junit.Platform.HtmlUnitLayout)` exists, but it would defeat the purpose of the test, as it does need HtmlUnit to actually run.

Comment: What do you mean it would defeat the purpose? If the HtmlUnit 'browser' doesn't support the APIs you need, how would it make sense for your test to run in HtmlUnit? What will you learn by running in a browser that can't run your code?

Comment: The script files causing the exception are absolutely not needed for a particular set of tests, but are getting loaded along with everything else. Not loading them at all for that particular set would be acceptable. It's doable when HtmlUnit is used as a standalone tool, but I cannot find a way to do so with GWT tests.

Comment: If the *module* being tested loads those files, then anything that runs that module must of course load them too. If you are loading them via a `<script>` tag in the module, consider breaking up the modules so that you can test a subset. If you are using ScriptInjector instead, then you need to find out why that script injector is running from apparently unrelated code.

Comment: Actually using something as inocuous as a test with just `assertEquals(100.0, 0.0);` it also attempts to launch HtmlUnit and load the scripts. If this test is annotated with `DoNotRunWith` HtmlUnit it apparently runs but gets marked as passed without actually running anything. It might be an issue with Eclipse's build settings rather than the module loading scripts.

Comment: Upon further investigation it seems like the script is referenced from the generated javascript file: `www-test/com.name.project.JUnit.nocache.js`
As for how/why I'm not too sure yet.

Comment: That strongly implies that you are referencing it from inside your module (that is, your `.gwt.xml` file). Since your test must declare a getModuleName method, I'm guessing you are declaring a module which has a `<script>` tag in it, so the module can't load without that file.

Comment: It was tricky to find out, but the script is getting included through module inheritance. I'm not quite sure how to resolve it, though as I shouldn't really be modifying the module I'm inheriting from, although the ideal solution would be separating the conflicting bit that uses that script to its own module to prevent its inclusion upon inheriting from the module it currently resides in.